# What is the best approach for .net core database hosting?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mongodb, .net-core

I have to build a web system to an insurance/finance company. So I'm having the idea to build the system using (.NET CORE). And this system will have secured/sensitive data and the database will be a growing one it should be secured.
So, what are the best database approaches when considering security, the size and all?
I was thinking of MongoDb or MySQL since hosting in Azure or SQL server will be more expensive. Client want to make it in cheaper way. 
I want to find out what is the cheapest way to build this app.

Comment: Taka a look at [this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/modern-web-apps-azure-architecture/azure-hosting-recommendations-for-asp-net-web-apps). Hope it will provide you some help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a broad question, and you note 2 different segments - the database and the total cost.  Looking at the database options:

Look at the data that will be stored in this database. What data types are there, will the client need access via script/query engine/report engine or just through the application interface? (Because for most, querying a SQL database is more straightforward.)

- Who will administer the DB? You? The client? What kind of experience does the DBA have? NoSQL databases are not the same animal, and with a mission critical, sensitive DB I would recommend you stay in step with the DBA's experience.
- How big will the database get? MySQL will handle the vast majority of company data needs.
- How complex does the DB design need to be to accommodate your application? (Should the DB design need to be complex, then a NoSQL approach may be better. But aim for the cleanest DB design you can while ensuring good performance times.)
- Where will this DB reside? Cloud-based on a hosted platform? On-premise? (Hosted allows the DB to grow easily and at less expense.)

All of these types of questions will decide what database engine will be best for this situation. I recommend you stay within familiar parameters to make development, deployment and administration easier, and likely faster. That will also save money.  Look at the total cost of ownership, not just the initial money that needs to be paid.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I will be the admin for the DB. DB will be growing faster and will be a big one since there can be many transactions since its an insurance and finance company. And Db will be reside on a hosted platform.